# Scrapy Link Extractors

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I am attempting to write some code using scrapy that will follow specific links to back up data on an adobe breeze web server. However, I am fairly new to scrapy and it's usage. The code is still in its early stages and much of what I have so far has been cobbled from the scrapy tutorial

My biggest issue so far has been scraping pages for links after initially logging in.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class LoginSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    start_urls = [
    'https://conted.breeze.und.nodak.edu/admin/meeting/folder/list?filter-rows=100&filter-start=0&sco-id=10003&tab-id=10003'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'login' : 'jake', 'password' : 'password'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "Invalid user or password. Please try again." in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return

    rules = (
        # Rule(LinkExtractor(deny_domains=['/admin/meeting?sco-id=10003&amp;tab-id=10003',
        #   '/admin/meeting?sco-id=10004&amp;tab-id=10004'])),
        #Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/admin/meeting?sco-id=\w+']), callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'\w+']), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('response.url=%s' % response.url)
```

the starting URL is the actual page I want to scrape links from but the server will prompt the user to log in with their credentials before being able to access that specific page. So in theory the response to this page would contain the links I am looking for. Although I am not receiving any results for my broad regex.

---

### Commented out code

the commented out rules were for specifiers for the links I needed to find in the following page. As you can see, I instead added a completely open regex to test for any links on the page. This returned the following [result](http://pastebin.com/RkSWjwik)

### Page Source

Although the actual page is behind a login, the source HTML for the main directory I am attempting to receive links from can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/kbByjYbV)

Comment: rules only work for the requests made of the `start_urls`, and the work on the `parse` method, so as you are overrinding that method, they are there for no reason

Comment: Ah, so the rule I wrote was just being ignored. I figured the rules would apply to any links scraped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend skipping rules and explicitly creating the request from `after_login()`

i.e. :

```
def after_login(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
    if "Invalid user or password. Please try again." in response.body:
        self.logger.error("Login failed")
    for href in response.selector.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
        url = response.urljoin(href)
        yield request(url, callback=self.parse_item)
```

Comment: Although if I placed this code snippet in that function it would only execute if the username or password was incorrect since the `for` loop is nested inside of the `if` statement that checks the validity of the login credentials. I should be able to use that code snippet in a different place in the code pretty easily though. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if the code is posted anywhere else, I get an error reading `globalname urljoin is not defined` I included all of my imports at the top of my code. Is there any import that I am missing to include urljoin?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Fixed the code.
urljoin requires `from urlparse import urljoin`. but last release of scrapy now provides response.urljoin () method which is more elegant